# Dotnet core SmtpClient - insert data in db on SendCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, callback, smtp, dbcontext

I have a .NET Core 3.1 app. The app should send emails, and log when the email is sent successfully (or not) into SQL Server database.

I have registered the database in the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataBaseAppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And I have registered my email sender in the same file like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

This is the `EmailSender` implementation:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
   private readonly DataBaseAppContext _context;

   public EmailSender(DataBaseAppContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }

   public Task SendEmailAsync(string subject, string message, string email)
   {
       return Execute(subject, message, email);
   }

    public Task Execute(string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        try
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(...);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = ...,
                Port = ...,
                ...
            };                

            MailMessage md = new MailMessage
            {
                From = ...,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Subject = subject,
                Body = message,
                To = ...
            };

            smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

            void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    //Want to use this statement as well, to log errors
                }
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    //Want to use this statement as well, to log errors
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                         //Object that should be saved in DB
                         EmailLogger emailLogger = new EmailLogger()
                         {
                             Email = email,
                             Subject = subject,
                             Message = message,
                             DateTime = DateTime.Now
                         };
                        _context.EmailLogger.Add(emailLogger);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Here I got an error - the *error below
                    }
                }
            }

            return smtp.SendMailAsync(md);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I call the `EmailSender.SendEmailAsync` I got the following error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

I understand this is caused because the service is registered as `AddTransient`, and the `_context` is already being disposed when the callback occurs.

Not sure what's the best way to resolve this, tried to change the `AddTransient` to `AddScoped` or `AddSingleton` just to see what will happen, but then got an error in the `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `SendMailAsync` method? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netcore-3.1 This method can be awaited and your context should not be disposed by the container.

I guess if you insist to use the callback method, you can inject the factory which will create the context for you when you need it (in the callback), and you can dispose the context yourself in the callback method.